# Run TensorFlow Federated on GPU with Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

Is there a way to **use the GPU provided by Colab** to run the **training sessions of TFF** faster?
Training Federated Models requires more than 1 hour and it seems that using a GPU runtime does not provide any benefit at all.

The TFF page of High-Performance Simulation is still empty and I cannot find any guide to use the GPU with TFF.

Any suggestion?
Thank you!

tf and tff versions:

```
2.4.0-dev20200917 
0.16.1
```

Number of clients at each round:

```
70
```

Input data element spec:

```
OrderedDict([('x',
          OrderedDict([('start_place',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
                       ('start_hour_sin',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)),
                       ('start_hour_cos',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)),
                       ('week_day_sin',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)),
                       ('week_day_cos',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)),
                       ('weekend',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
                       ('month',
                        TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])),
         ('y', TensorSpec(shape=(8, 8), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])
```

Similarly to the text generation tutorial i'm working with sequence of places, the model is quite similar:

```
    # Create a model
def create_keras_model(number_of_places, batch_size):
  
        # Shortcut to the layers package
  l = tf.keras.layers


  # Now we need to define an input dictionary.
    # Where the keys are the column names
    # This is a model with multiple inputs, so we need to declare and input layer for each feature
  feature_inputs = {
    'start_hour_sin': tf.keras.Input((N-1, ), batch_size=batch_size, name='start_hour_sin'),
    'start_hour_cos': tf.keras.Input((N-1, ), batch_size=batch_size, name='start_hour_cos'),
    'weekend': tf.keras.Input((N-1, ), batch_size=batch_size, name='weekend'),
    'week_day_sin': tf.keras.Input((N-1, ), batch_size=batch_size, name='week_day_sin'),
    'week_day_cos': tf.keras.Input((N-1, ), batch_size=batch_size, name='week_day_cos'),
  }

  
  # We cannot use anarray of features as always because we have sequences and we cannot match the shape otherwise
  # We have to do one by one
  start_hour_sin = feature_column.numeric_column("start_hour_sin", shape=(N-1))
  hour_sin_feature = l.DenseFeatures(start_hour_sin)(feature_inputs)

  start_hour_cos = feature_column.numeric_column("start_hour_cos", shape=(N-1))
  hour_cos_feature = l.DenseFeatures(start_hour_cos)(feature_inputs)

  weekend = feature_column.numeric_column("weekend", shape=(N-1))
  weekend_feature = l.DenseFeatures(weekend)(feature_inputs)
  
  week_day_sin = feature_column.numeric_column("week_day_sin", shape=(N-1))
  week_day_sin_feature = l.DenseFeatures(week_day_sin)(feature_inputs)

  week_day_cos = feature_column.numeric_column("week_day_cos", shape=(N-1))
  week_day_cos_feature = l.DenseFeatures(week_day_cos)(feature_inputs)

  
    # We have also to add a dimension to then concatenate
  hour_sin_feature = tf.expand_dims(hour_sin_feature, -1)
  hour_cos_feature = tf.expand_dims(hour_cos_feature, -1)
  weekend_feature = tf.expand_dims(weekend_feature, -1)
  week_day_sin_feature = tf.expand_dims(week_day_sin_feature, -1)
  week_day_cos_feature = tf.expand_dims(week_day_cos_feature, -1)

  # Declare the dictionary for the places sequence as before
  sequence_input = {
      'start_place': tf.keras.Input((N-1,), batch_size=batch_size, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, name='start_place') # add batch_size=batch_size in case of stateful GRU
  }


  # Handling the categorical feature sequence using one-hot
  places_one_hot = feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'start_place', [i for i in range(number_of_places)])
  
  # Embed the one-hot encoding
  places_embed = feature_column.embedding_column(places_one_hot, embedding_dim)


  # With an input sequence we can't use the DenseFeature layer, we need to use the SequenceFeatures
  sequence_features, sequence_length = tf.keras.experimental.SequenceFeatures(places_embed)(sequence_input)

  input_sequence = l.Concatenate(axis=2)([ sequence_features, hour_sin_feature, hour_cos_feature, weekend_feature, week_day_sin_feature, week_day_cos_feature])

  # Rnn
  recurrent = l.GRU(rnn_units,
                        batch_size=batch_size, #in case of stateful
                        return_sequences=True,
                        dropout=0.5,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')(input_sequence)


    # Last layer with an output for each places
  dense_1 = layers.Dense(number_of_places)(recurrent)

    # Softmax output layer
  output = l.Softmax()(dense_1)
    
    # To return the Model, we need to define it's inputs and outputs
    # In out case, we need to list all the input layers we have defined 
  inputs = list(feature_inputs.values()) + list(sequence_input.values())

    # Return the Model
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

Function to create the model:

```
def create_tff_model():
  # TFF uses an `input_spec` so it knows the types and shapes
  # that your model expects.
  input_spec = preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec
  keras_model_clone = create_keras_model(number_of_places, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model_clone,
      input_spec=input_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
```

Federated Avg

```
# This command builds all the TensorFlow graphs and serializes them: 
fed_avg = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn=create_tff_model,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.06))
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

State init:

```
state = fed_avg.initialize()
```

Training Loop:

```
NUM_ROUNDS = 10

  for round_num in range(1, NUM_ROUNDS + 1):
    print('Round {r}'.format(r=round_num))
    state, metrics = fed_avg.next(state, train_data)
    train_metrics = metrics['train']
    print('\tTrain: loss={l:.3f}, accuracy={a:.3f}'.format(l=train_metrics['loss'], a=train_metrics['sparse_categorical_accuracy']))
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What version of TF and TFF do you use? What is the model and task you are training? How many clients per round do you use? All such additional details, perhaps code snippet about how you provide data, would be helpful.

Comment: Please share a self-contained, public notebook that reproduces the performance pathologies you observe.

Comment: Sorry @JakubKonecny, Bob. I have added additional details and snippets

Comment: Could you comment on the sizes of `train_data`? There are 70 clients, but how many examples, batches, and epochs are the datasets setup with?

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett the average number of training batches per user is around 13, while the number of epochs per client is 2

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem: about 8 hours for a single round of training (1 epoch) using 3 clients, while training the same image classification model (MobileNet) on the same dataset requires less than an hour per epoch. GPU utilization is 0%, cpu is 1500%.

Answer (score 1):

To note this model is performing  0 clients * 13 steps of SGD per round (close to 1,000), though one hour still seems very long. 70 clients on a single machine is pushing the limits of the simulation, when the number grows much higher we start to look at multi-machine setups using the remote executor.

Some things to investigate:

- Is the simulation *I/O* bound? How fast can the Python environment iterate over a single client dataset? In TF `for batch in dataset:` and time how long it takes might be useful here.
- Is the simulation *compute* bound? Maybe watch the CPU and GPU utilization. How long does it take to run `keras_model.fit()` on a single client dataset? The TFF simulation is roughly doing this 70x per round (once for each client).

Comment: Using the same dataset in a common centralized context took me 4s per epoch and 7ms/step.
A keras_model.fit() called on one client dataset takes roughly 3 seconds to compute the 2 epochs i set per clients (2 seconds of training and 1s to start since i call the function); So only the clients' fit() should take something like 70*3s = 210s which is roughly exactly the time it takes per round (170s on average)